# Why don't we start evolution with ground state in QAOAnsatz?

Tags: optimization, qaoa

The adiabatic theorem states that we can start from an eigenstate, slowly change our Hamiltonian and still remain in the eigenstate. In the vanilla QAOA we start from $|+\rangle^n$, which is the eigenstate of the default mixer $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, $n$ - number of qubits. However, in the Quantum Alternating Operator Ansatz we design some complicated mixers and only require the initial state to be one of the feasible states, completely forgetting about the eigenstate requirement. Why?

I've read somewhere that the initial state just needs to overlap with an eigenstate, but I checked it numerically and for the 4-qubit [onehot mixer](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/12/2/34) the feasible onehot states are nowhere near to the onehot mixer eigenstates.